# CWnd::SetRedraw(False) make mouse go throught window

Tags: c++, mfc, cwnd

So I have a MFC application which flick when we do some action. 
So I figured I would set `SetRedraw(false)` and set it to true at the end of the function.

The application doesn't refresh anymore but if I click on it while `SetRedraw(false)`, my cursor is not catched by my application, it goes throught it and set focus on the application below.

Anyone has some kind of idea how I could fix that.

Comment: This question is lacking in all respects, and cannot be answered beyond a useless *"You are doing it wrong"* remark. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It doesn't look like you got yourself the *Informed* badge either, so you might want to consider taking the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as well.

Comment: I'll pass. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `CWnd::LockWindowUpdate` instead after some research.
It freezes the update but doesn't act if the window was transparent.